# Silverlight Web.Config Setting for Web Service Reference URL?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, web-services, web-config

I have a Silverlight control that is hosted within an ASP.NET application.  The Silverlight control has a web service reference.  The URL of this service is going to vary when we install the application for our customers.  I need a way to be able to change this web service reference URL from within the web.config of the ASP.NET application.  How can I do this?

Comment: You looked here? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightWebConfig.aspx

Comment: @Aaron I did see that, but I don't know how I will be able to pull a URL out from that config file and apply it to my web service reference.  That's the second half of puzzle.

Comment: Are you creating a client within SL via EndPointAddress? If so you would need to then make use of the code project article, and reference the passed in data as you construct your service via the EndPointAddress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like http://dev/foo/bar.svc where dev is an entry in your [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) file which will resolve to where the service resides.

Comment: Good idea!  I was hoping to get this to work with web.config, but I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Silverlight 4 you can use urls relative to the page the silverlight app is hosted on. So in ServiceReferences.ClientConfig you can change your endpoint addresses to be relative, say from `http://localhost/foo/bar.svc` to `/foo/bar.svc`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for.  The server that hosts the web service is elsewhere in the network.  I simply need to be able to change the server name.